# Extending ProgressBarUI for modifying the look of a JProgressBar in Java

Tags: java, swing, gui, graphics

I have this visual mod for a `javax.swing.JProgressBar`:

[image: The new look for <code>JProgressBar</code>]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.ProgressBarUI;

/**
 * This class implements coderodde's UI for {@code javax.swing.JProgressBar}.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class FunkyProgressBarUI extends ProgressBarUI {

    /**
     * The default background color.
     */
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    /**
     * The default border color.
     */
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.RED;

    /**
     * The default progress bar color.
     */
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BAR_COLOR = Color.PINK;

    /**
     * The minimum border thickness in pixels.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_BORDER_THICKNESS = 0;

    /**
     * The maximum border thickness in pixels.
     */
    private static final int MAXIMUM_BORDER_THICKNESS = 10;

    /**
     * The default border thickness in pixels.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_THICKNESS = 4;

    /**
     * The default font for drawing the percentage.
     */
    private static final Font DEFAULT_FONT = 
            new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30); 

    /**
     * The background color.
     */
    private Color backgroundColor;

    /**
     * The border color.
     */
    private Color borderColor;

    /**
     * The progress bar color.
     */
    private Color barColor;

    /**
     * The thickness of the border in pixels.
     */
    private int borderThickness;

    /**
     * The font for drawing percentage.
     */
    private Font font;

    /**
     * Creates a new UI for a {@link javax.swing.JProgressBar} with default
     * attributes.
     */
    public FunkyProgressBarUI() {
        setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        setBorderColor(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        setBarColor(DEFAULT_BAR_COLOR);
        setBorderThickness(DEFAULT_BORDER_THICKNESS);
        setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(final Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(final Color borderColor) {
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    public void setBarColor(final Color barColor) {
        this.barColor = barColor;
    }

    public void setBorderThickness(final int thickness) {
        this.borderThickness = Math.max(MINIMUM_BORDER_THICKNESS, 
                                        Math.min(MAXIMUM_BORDER_THICKNESS, 
                                                 thickness));
    }

    public void setFont(final Font font) {
        this.font = font;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics g, final JComponent component) {
        update(g, component);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(final Graphics g, final JComponent component) {
        final int WIDTH = component.getWidth();
        final int HEIGHT = component.getHeight();

        //// Draw the border.
        g.setColor(borderColor);
        // Upper horizontal border.
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, borderThickness);
        // Lower horizontal border.
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - borderThickness, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        // Left vertical border.
        g.fillRect(0, 
                   borderThickness, 
                   borderThickness, 
                   HEIGHT - 2 * borderThickness);
        // Right vertical border.
        g.fillRect(WIDTH - borderThickness,
                   borderThickness,
                   borderThickness,
                   HEIGHT - 2 * borderThickness);

        final double percentageReady = 
                ((JProgressBar) component).getPercentComplete();
        final int width = (int)((WIDTH - 2 * borderThickness) * 
                                 percentageReady / 2.0);

        //// Draw the bar and more.
        g.setColor(barColor);
        g.fillRect(borderThickness,
                   borderThickness,
                   WIDTH - 2 * borderThickness,
                   HEIGHT - 2 * borderThickness);

        //// Fill the exposed background.
        if (percentageReady < 1.0) {
            g.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g.fillRect(borderThickness + width,
                       borderThickness, 
                       WIDTH - 2 * borderThickness - 2 * width,
                       HEIGHT - 2 * borderThickness);
        }

        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        g.setXORMode(barColor);

        final FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        final String str = "" + (int)(100 * percentageReady) + "%";
        final int stringHeight = fm.getHeight();
        final int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(str);
        g.drawString(str, 
                     (WIDTH - stringWidth) >>> 1, 
                     ((HEIGHT + stringHeight) >>> 1) - fm.getDescent());
    }

    /**
     * The entry point to the demo program.
     * 
     * @param args ignored.
     */
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final int MIN_VALUE = 0;
        final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
        final int AVERAGE = (MIN_VALUE + MAX_VALUE) >>> 1;

        // Create all the GUI components.
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FunkyProgressBarUI");
        final JProgressBar bar1 = new JProgressBar(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
        final JProgressBar bar2 = new JProgressBar(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
        final JSlider slider = new JSlider(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, AVERAGE);
        final Dimension dim = new Dimension(301, 70);
        final FunkyProgressBarUI ui = new FunkyProgressBarUI();
        final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10);

        // Let slider to modify the second progress bar.
        slider.addChangeListener(new MySliderChangeListener(bar2));

        // Prepare the bars.
        bar1.setPreferredSize(dim);
        bar2.setPreferredSize(dim);
        bar2.setValue(slider.getValue());

        // Make them Funky.
        bar1.setUI(ui);
        bar2.setUI(ui);

        // Constructing the GUI.
        frame.setLayout(layout);
        frame.add(bar1);
        frame.add(slider);
        frame.add(bar2);
        frame.pack();

        final Dimension screenDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // Move the frame to the center of the screen.
        frame.setLocation((screenDim.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2,
                          (screenDim.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

        // Almost ready.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Let the thread do its job.
        new UpdateThread(bar1, 3, 100L).start();
    }

    /**
     * Listens to the changes in a {@link javax.swing.JSlider} and updates a
     * {@link javax.swing.JProgressBar}.
     */
    private static final class MySliderChangeListener 
    implements ChangeListener {

        /**
         * The target <code>JProgressBar</code> to update.
         */
        private final JProgressBar bar;

        /**
         * Constructs a new listener with given target.
         * 
         * @param bar the target <code>JProgressBar</code>.
         */
        public MySliderChangeListener(final JProgressBar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        /**
         * Updates the target <code>JProgressBar</code>.
         * 
         * @param e the event.
         */
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(final ChangeEvent e) {
            bar.setValue(((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue());
            bar.repaint();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread modifies the value of a {@link javax.swing.JProgressBar}. It
     * increases the value of a bar to its maximum, after which it starts to 
     * decrease it. Once the minimum value is attained, this thread begins to
     * increase it, and so on.
     */
    private static final class UpdateThread extends Thread {

        /**
         * The minimum difference in the <code>bar</code>'s value.
         */
        private static final int MINIMUM_STEP = 1;

        /**
         * The minimum sleeping duration in milliseconds.
         */
        private static final long MINIMUM_SLEEP_DURATION = 10L;

        /**
         * The {@link javax.swing.JProgressBar} to modify.
         */
        private final JProgressBar bar;

        /**
         * The amount by which the value <code>bar</code> is changed.
         */
        private final int step;

        /**
         * The duration of sleeping in milliseconds.
         */
        private final long sleepDuration;

        /**
         * Constructs a new update thread.
         * 
         * @param bar           the target <code>JProgressBar</code>.
         * @param step          the step to use.
         * @param sleepDuration the sleep duration.
         */
        UpdateThread(final JProgressBar bar, 
                     final int step,
                     final long sleepDuration) {
            this.bar = bar;
            this.step = Math.max(step, MINIMUM_STEP);
            this.sleepDuration = Math.max(sleepDuration, 
                                          MINIMUM_SLEEP_DURATION);
        }

        /**
         * The entry point into this thread.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean increase = true;
            bar.setValue(bar.getMinimum());

            for (;;) {
                trySleep(sleepDuration);

                if (increase) {
                    bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + step);

                    if (bar.getValue() >= bar.getMaximum()) {
                        // Change direction.
                        increase = !increase;
                    }
                } else {
                    bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - step);

                    if (bar.getValue() <= bar.getMinimum()) {
                        // Change direction.
                        increase = !increase;
                    }
                }

                bar.repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Attempts to sleep the calling thread for <code>milliseconds</code>
         * milliseconds.
         * 
         * @param milliseconds the duration of a sleep.
         */
        private static final void trySleep(final long milliseconds) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
            } catch (final InterruptedException ie) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to ask:

1. Is this the right way to modify the look of a Swing component?
2. Is there enough comments in the code?
3. How do you like the new simplistic look?
4. Is there room for making the drawing routine more cohesive?
5. How can I make the percentage string appear more sharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A more appropriate way would be to implement your own LookAndFeel, this might include registering your own resources to UIManager, write your own LookAndFeel class as well as your own UI class for each and every component. Start with reading the metal look and feel source code, and extend from it.
2. would be personal opinion so I won't answer this one
3. would be personal opinion so I won't answer this one either :)
4. It's a matter of your OO skills, write more code and read [Effective Java 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683)
5. check RenderingHints class, KEY_ANTIALIASING and VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON constant, also the related method on Graphics2D

BTW, the threads in your program is incorrect, maybe it's good to do some search on Swing application thread rules, or (better) read the [Filthy Rich Clients](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132413930) book.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Code Review! Good first answer. For the books, if you want to add links to them, you can do so via `[Link text](url)`.

Comment: Thanks Pimgd :-)
I've edited the answer to link the books.